# Error de redefinición de método en una clase plantilla

Tags: c++, template

Buen dia comunidad, quisiera que me ayudaran con un error que tengo en un intento de implementacion de una clase nodo en c++

```
#ifndef NODO_H_
#define NODO_H_

template <class T>
class Nodo{
private:
    T element;
    Nodo<T>* siguiente;
public:
    Nodo<T>(T, Nodo<T>*);
    T getV();
    void setV(T);
    Nodo<T>* getSiguiente();
    void setSiguiente(Nodo<T>*);
    void toString();
};

#endif /* NODO_H_ */
```

este es my header

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Nodo.h"
template <class T>
Nodo<T>* Nodo<T>::getSiguiente(){
    return siguiente;
}
template <class T>
T Nodo<T>::getV(){
    return element;
}
template <class T>
Nodo<T>::Nodo(T elemento, Nodo<T>* next){
    this->element= elemento;
    this->siguiente = next;
}
template <class T>
void Nodo<T>::setSiguiente(Nodo<T>* newNext){
    this->siguiente= newNext;
}
template <class T>
void Nodo<T>::setV(T element){
    this->element= element;
}
```

y este es mi source file. El error que tengo es redefinition of 'Nodo* Nodo::getSiguiente()' en el primer metodo y asi en todos los demas

Comment: Las plantillas no se pueden separar en archivo de cabecera y archivo de código (a no ser que en el archivo de código vaya una especialización, que no es tu caso) deben ir la declaración y la definición en el archivo de cabecera. Por otro lado añades tu código pero no cómo lo usas y el problema está en el uso que le das.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster sí se pueden separar... pero en ese caso la implementación debe estar referenciada en la cabecera con un include... justo al revés que con el código no basado en plantillas.

Comment: @eferion un `include` es un copia-pega de un archivo en otro, a la práctica están en el mismo sitio tras el pre-procesado. Por otro lado un archivo de código (`cpp`) con definiciones de plantilla no compila nada a no ser que contenga una especialización de la plantilla. Conclusión: declaración y definición de la plantilla van juntos a no ser que sean especializaciones de plantilla, en cuyo caso: puede ir separado.

Answer (score 1):

Las plantillas son diferentes a las clases tradicionales. A partir de una plantilla no se genera código compilable directamente ya que hay tipos que no están determinados ¿Qué es `T`?

Cuando el compilador está procesando una clase generará código binario correspondiente a la misma. Será responsabilidad del enlazador crear las llamadas correspondientes a estas porciones de código ya compiladas. Sin embargo, al encontrarse con una plantilla el compilador no va a generar código binario alguno. Se esperará a encontrar usos de dicha plantilla para poder crear todas las versiones que sean necesarias. Así, ante el siguiente código:

```
Nodo<int> nodo(5,nullptr);
Nodo<char> nodo('c',nullptr);
```

El compilador creará dos clases `Nodo` diferentes a partir de la plantilla: `Nodo<int>` y `Nodo<char>`, y sin embargo tu programa no tendrá código referente a la especialización `Nodo<float>`, por ejemplo. A nivel de código serán clases independientes que no tendrán herencia común ni nada por el estilo.

Pues bien, para que esta *magia* se pueda obrar es necesario que **todo** el código que involucra a la plantilla esté disponible allá donde se use, de tal forma que el compilador pueda crear las especializaciones que se necesiten.

Tu problema es que estás separando la declaración de la implementación y, al encontrarse el compilador con usos de la plantilla, se da cuenta de que no tiene la implementación de la plantilla y falla.

Lo más común, en el caso de plantillas, es embeber todo el código en el fichero de cabecera:

```
#ifndef NODO_H_
#define NODO_H_

template <class T>
class Nodo{
private:
    T element;
    Nodo<T>* siguiente;
public:
    Nodo<T>(T, Nodo<T>*);
    T getV();
    void setV(T);
    Nodo<T>* getSiguiente();
    void setSiguiente(Nodo<T>*);
    void toString();
};

template <class T>
Nodo<T>* Nodo<T>::getSiguiente(){
    return siguiente;
}
template <class T>
T Nodo<T>::getV(){
    return element;
}
template <class T>
Nodo<T>::Nodo(T elemento, Nodo<T>* next){
    this->element= elemento;
    this->siguiente = next;
}
template <class T>
void Nodo<T>::setSiguiente(Nodo<T>* newNext){
    this->siguiente= newNext;
}
template <class T>
void Nodo<T>::setV(T element){
    this->element= element;
}

#endif /* NODO_H_ */
```

Aunque si no te parece una opción demasiado legible podrás separar el código en dos archivos o más. Lo único que tienes que garantizar es que el código de la plantilla al completo esté disponible allá donde se haga uso de la misma.

Una solución pasa por usar un mecanismo de `#include`. En este caso el *include* se pondrá en la cabecera y hará referencia al fichero de implementación... justo al contrario a como se hace con las clases normales:

```
#ifndef NODO_H_
#define NODO_H_

template <class T>
class Nodo{
private:
    T element;
    Nodo<T>* siguiente;
public:
    Nodo<T>(T, Nodo<T>*);
    T getV();
    void setV(T);
    Nodo<T>* getSiguiente();
    void setSiguiente(Nodo<T>*);
    void toString();
};

#include "nodo.cpp"

#endif /* NODO_H_ */
```

Y, por supuesto, elimina el *include* correspondiente en el fichero de implementación:

```
#include <iostream>
// #include "Nodo.h" <-- Eliminar

template <class T>
Nodo<T>* Nodo<T>::getSiguiente(){
    return siguiente;
}

// ...
```

Por supuesto, este último fichero de código no debes intentar compilarlo. Es más una extensión de la cabecera que un fichero de implementación al uso.

Comment: El problema que se encuentra es que define dos veces las funciones de la plantilla, no que no encuentre una definición en concreto.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster lo se, con lo que comento se soluciona, cierto?

Comment: No estoy seguro, porque falta el caso de uso, pero parece que tu solución se centra en resolver "*Undefined reference to...*" no en resolver "*Redefinition of...*".

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster La redefinición me da que aparece porque el compilador ya ha intentado crear una versión del nodo en otro fichero y esa versión (que no va a enlazar de ninguna manera) se solapa con la que intenta crear al compilar `nodo.cpp`

Comment: Yo he probado el código tal y como está puesto por el autor original (pero todo en el mismo archivo) y compila sin errores. Sin el caso de uso no puedo hacer más que conjeturas. Tu aproximación soluciona el problema porque a la práctica hace lo mismo que mi prueba: pone todo en el mismo archivo. Pero tu explicación se centra en la falta de definiciones ("*[...] al encontrarse el compilador con usos de la plantilla, se da cuenta de que no tiene la implementación de la plantilla y falla*) no en el exceso de las mismas (que es el problema real).